# Perl see the full content in response

Tags: perl

I need to take data from html page, so I am using LWP to get the page content.
the response I got is partial and not the full source of the page.

...

```
<div style="display:none" id="QUERY" query=""></div>
<div style="display:none" id="COLL" idcoll=""></div>
<div style="display:none" id="BROWSE" field=""></div>

<div id="center"></div>
<div id="loading"></div>
```

...

when using a web debugger(FIRE BUG) I can see a hidden content under:

```
<div id="center"></div>
<div id="loading"></div>
```

How can I get the hidden data using Perl ?

It breaks my mind for 3 days now !
Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 3):

> let's say it a JS running... How can i
>   see the content?

You could use [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox). It seems to support Javascript.

Comment: It supports Javascript, if you have Javascript enabled in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

If the content is indeed added using Javascript, you might be able to use [WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aScripter) with the Javascript or Ajax plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not present in the HTML source that LWP fetches, it is added in some other way. There probably is a Javascript running, or the webserver serves you and LWP different pages because of cookies or user agent string.

Comment: Thanks, but let's say it a JS running... How can i see the content?

Comment: @GrinGo: It completely depends on the Javascript. We need more code to say anything. Perhaps it computes something on the fly, perhaps it makes an AJAX request.

Comment: @GrinGo: Investigate the complete HTML source of the page, searching for scripts. It looks like Eugene has a simpler solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or use the Safari Develop menu to see what AJAX/XHR requests are being done to the server, and with what POST/GET parameters. You can then use LWP or any other HTTP client module to do such a request.